Add translator info in cite command
I am trying to add the translator information into the cite command (I have already amended it for my needs to the bibliography itself).
IF the publication does not have an author or editor, the translator is printed in cite, which is correct. In addition I want to add the information, that it is the translator. (I am using German, so the translator info will be printed in German Übers.)
E.g.
for textcite:
Lastname (Übers.) (2010: 1-2)
for parencite:
(Lastname (Übers.) 2010: 1-2)
Bibliography example entry:
@incollection{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature,
    translator = {Kern, Martin},
    booktitle = {The Cambridge History of Chinese Literature},
    date = {2010-04-01},
    isbn = {978-1-139-09541-9},
    pages = {1--115},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    title = {Early Chinese Literature, Beginnings Through Western Han},
    }

(This is just an example)
MWE:

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIB
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}% avoid bib formatting issues

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\textcite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}

\parencite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}

\autocite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}

\cite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}
\nocite{*} 
\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}


Note that you could minimise this example. Assuming it is not Koma-specific, use a standard class. We surely don't need your font config!

I get an error when I try to compile as-is: ! Package xkeyval Error: pagetotal' undefined in families blx@opt@pre'. Could you please correct it?

Thank you @cfr I have reduced the MWE and removed the error causing line.

We can adapt the idea from BibLaTex - mark editor in cite and bibligraphy (labelname). Essentially we check labelnamesource for the type of name (author/editor/translator) we have and use the suitable bibmacro for that job. Then we just need to redefine cite and tetxcite so that they print the augmented name.
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
}

\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}% avoid bib formatting issues

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

\newbibmacro{cite:labelname}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{editor}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{translator}
         {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
         {}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}%
          \csuse{extblx@citedelim@\blx@delimcontext @inner@open}}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}%
       \csuse{extblx@citedelim@\blx@delimcontext @inner@open}}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature,
    translator = {Kern, Martin},
    booktitle = {The Cambridge History of Chinese Literature},
    date = {2010-04-01},
    isbn = {978-1-139-09541-9},
    pages = {1--115},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    title = {Early Chinese Literature, Beginnings Through Western Han},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}

\parencite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}

\autocite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}

\cite[][1--2]{Kern.2010-EarlyChineseLiterature}
\nocite{*} 
\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}



Thank you @moewe that worked beautifully!
